# Cordova Android app crashes when <select> element is clicked

Tags: android, html, cordova

everyone,

I created a HelloWorld app, with a single  element, using cordova 3.6.3, and I am building and testing it in two android versions: KitKat and L.

It works fine when running on KitKat, but on L it crashes when clicking on the select element.

Did anybody experience something similar? Does anybody know how to fix this?

More info:

The only file I modified was the index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <select>
                <option value="1">Opt1</option>
                <option value="2">Opt2</option>
                <option value="3">Opt3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The logcat output for when it crashes:

```
D/InputTransport(  629): Input channel constructed: name='2106db22 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova (server)', fd=407
D/InputTransport(  629): Input channel constructed: name='2106db22 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova (client)', fd=409
D/WindowManager(  629):  new Window{2106db22 u0 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova} type 2 flags = 25296898 user 0
D/InputDispatcher(  629): Focus left window: Window{323f5035 u0 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova}
D/InputDispatcher(  629): Focus entered window: Window{2106db22 u0 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova}
D/InputTransport(  629): Input channel destroyed: name='2106db22 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova (client)', fd=409
E/SMD     (  303): DCD ON
D/InputTransport(13007): Input channel constructed: name='2106db22 br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld.HelloCordova (client)', fd=151
W/ResourceType(13007): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
D/AndroidRuntime(13007): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(13007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13007): Process: br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld, PID: 13007
E/AndroidRuntime(13007): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2103)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3494)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1919)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:413)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2520)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1275)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1187)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5714)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5714)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5714)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5714)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5714)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5714)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2792)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18084)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2193)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1146)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6465)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime(13007):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1174)
W/ActivityManager(  629):   Force finishing activity br.eti.earruda.app.helloworld/.HelloCordova
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want this to work on android 5.0? And do you have installed android 5.0 (lollipop) with your sdk manager?

Comment: I have a device running Lollipop. I'm building an app that has this issue and I did this on a simple app to isolate the problem.

Comment: Oke, and you have downloaded all the right stuff from your sdk manager and told your manifest that you are programming for Lolipop?

Comment: As I used cordova to create and build the project, I did not change anything on the platform specific code.

Comment: Can you check what's the targetSdk version in your AndroidManifest.xml? (maybe lowering it may help solve the issue)

Comment: Manifest:

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

project.properties:

    target=android-19